# Bluetooth SPP server using Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, spp

I want to communicate with a [Sepura STP8000 radio](https://www.sepura.com/products/stp8x000) from a Flutter app via Bluetooth (specifically SPP, Serial Port Protocol).

I first tried the [flutter_bluetooth_serial](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bluetooth_serial) and was able to connect and communicate successfully with another Android device running [a Bluetooth Terminal app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nudge.me.TermFree), sending text back and forth. But when I tried connecting to the Sepura radio I was out of luck. With my basic understanding of Bluetooth, I'm under the impression that the Sepura can only act as a client, so I would need my Flutter app to start a server and listen for an incoming connection (but I might be wrong).

So instead I tried the [bluetoothadapter](https://pub.dev/packages/bluetoothadapter) plugin, which seems to be able to act as a server (at least it has a `startServer()` method). That didn't work either. I was unable to connect from the Sepura, and also unable to connect from another Android device, so I'm not sure if `startServer()` actually starts a SPP server or not.

Any ideas for how I can listen for incoming Bluetooth SPP connections in my Flutter app? It's fine if it only works on either Android or iOS, as long as it works on one of them.